# How do I correct the Error, "Image not found"

Tags: moderncv

When I compile this code the error that appeared is `LaTeX Error: File '1053817122' not found`.

I wish for this image (that is not found) to appear in my pdf with a  height of 4 centimeters and a width of 3 centimeters.

[image]

This is the code I have Used

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

\firstname{Juan Pablo} % Your first name
\familyname{Muñoz Diaz} % Your last name

\title{Hoja de Vida}
\mobile{321 643 9819}
\email{jpmunozd@unal.edu.co}

\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{1053817122} 

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to have the jpg file in the same directory as your tex file.  Then everything should work.

Comment: Perhaps you also need to include the jpg in the filename. So put it into the same directory as the tex file and use `\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{1053817122.jpg}`.